# Tf has two or more unconnected trees

Tags: ros-kinetic, transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey!
I was trying to use a Kinect fusion package for my project on [Robot Workcell Discovery](https://github.com/ros-industrial/workcell_explorer). I am using ROS Kinetic and Ubuntu 16.04.

While launching the Kinect fusion node, I face the following error.

`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf2::LookupException'. what():  Could not find a connection between 'volume_pose' and 'camera_depth_optical_frame' because they are not part of the same tree. Tf has two or more unconnected trees.`

How as per the [Link to the tf frames.pdf file generated](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ViUNkJNJhRs_f-AKHxkF8p-XM0vH8qkM/view?usp=sharing) created using `rosrun tf view_frames` these two frames seem to be in the same tree.

On some occasions, the same launch file gives the following error.
`terminate called after throwing an instance of 'tf2::LookupException' what():  "volume_pose" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.`

This is the related code

```
if (!camera->nodeHandle.getParam("use_pose_hints", use_pose_hints_)) 
{
    ROS_INFO("Failed to get use_pose_hints flag!");
  }
 ROS_INFO_STREAM("Use pose hints set to " << use_pose_hints_);
 tfListener_.waitForTransform("volume_pose", "camera_depth_optical_frame", ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(2));
tfListener_.lookupTransform("volume_pose", "camera_depth_optical_frame", ros::Time(0), previous_volume_to_sensor_transform_);
 }
    }
```

I have added Listener. waitForTransform() as mentioned in [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/41980/tf-has-two-or-more-unconnected-trees-error/). I have also added     `<param name="/use_sim_time" value="true"/>` on the top of my launch files as as mentioned by some other answers, however the problem still persists.

There definitely seems to be a problem of the `volume_pose` not being available in time. What could be the potential reason and solution for this issue?

**Edit:** In one case, I received this error message as well which according to [this link](http://wiki.ros.org/tf/Errors%20explained) is again due to a delayed source of frames.

`Warning: TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame table at time 0.165 according to authority unknown_publisher`

**Output of tf monitor**

```
Waiting for transform chain to become available between volume_pose and camera_depth_optical_frame 

RESULTS: for volume_pose to camera_depth_optical_frame
 Chain is: volume_pose -> base_link -> table -> world -> shoulder_link -> upper_arm_link -> forearm_link -> wrist_1_link -> wrist_2_link -> wrist_3_link -> tool0 -> camera_link -> camera_depth_frame -> camera_depth_optical_frame
Net delay     avg = 0.00997896: max = 0.099
        
Frames:
Frame: base_link published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_depth_frame published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_depth_optical_frame published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: camera_link published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: forearm_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000272727 Max Delay: 0.003
Frame: shoulder_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000272727 Max Delay: 0.003
Frame: table published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: -0.0666667 Max Delay: 0
Frame: tool0 published by unknown_publisher(static) Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: upper_arm_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000272727 Max Delay: 0.003
Frame: volume_pose published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
Frame: wrist_1_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000272727 Max Delay: 0.003
Frame: wrist_2_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000272727 Max Delay: 0.003
Frame: wrist_3_link published by unknown_publisher Average Delay: 0.000272727 Max Delay: 0.003
        
All Broadcasters:
Node: unknown_publisher 85 Hz, Average Delay: -0.0233529 Max Delay: 0.003
Node: unknown_publisher(static) 1e+08 Hz, Average Delay: 0 Max Delay: 0
```

Thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/295359/tf-has-two-or-more-unconnected-trees/) by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) on ROS Answers with karma: 105 on 2018-06-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!

Just for anyone facing a similar issue in the future.

Instead of

```
if (!camera->nodeHandle.getParam("use_pose_hints", use_pose_hints_)) 
{
    ROS_INFO("Failed to get use_pose_hints flag!");
  }
 ROS_INFO_STREAM("Use pose hints set to " << use_pose_hints_);
 tfListener_.waitForTransform("volume_pose", "camera_depth_optical_frame", ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(2));
tfListener_.lookupTransform("volume_pose", "camera_depth_optical_frame", ros::Time(0), previous_volume_to_sensor_transform_);
 }
    }
```

I added a try-catch block as per the tf tutorials.

```
if (use_pose_hints_) {
    try {
  tfListener_.waitForTransform("volume_pose", "camera_depth_optical_frame", ros::Time::now(), ros::Duration(0.5));
  tfListener_.lookupTransform("volume_pose", "camera_depth_optical_frame", ros::Time(0), previous_volume_to_sensor_transform_);
    }
    catch (tf::TransformException ex){
        ROS_ERROR("%s", ex.what());
    }
}
```

}

This allowed time for the `volume_pose` frame to become available when the Kinect fusion node was launched.

And in case the frame is not available the following message will be shown.

```
[ERROR] [1530122898.477899539, 10.817000000]: "volume_pose" passed to lookupTransform argument target_frame does not exist.
```

Refer to [this issue](https://github.com/AustinDeric/yak/issues/18) and [this pull request](https://github.com/AustinDeric/yak/pull/19) if more details are required.

---

Originally posted by [aaditya_saraiya](https://answers.ros.org/users/31473/aaditya_saraiya/) with karma: 105 on 2018-06-27

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0